# Revit 2014 API PromptForFamilyInstancePlacement method

Tags: c#, instance, revit

i am trying load Revit files using loadrevitfamily() and wants the user to place specific family symbol on current project in Revit. my code is follows:

```
public void loadRevitFamily(String f)
    {
        //Filename without extension
        String fname = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(f);

        Family family = null;
        FamilySymbol familyFound = null;

        Transaction t = new Transaction(s_document, "Test");
        t.Start();

        s_document.LoadFamily(f, out family);
        t.Commit();
        FilteredElementCollector familyCollector = new FilteredElementCollector(s_document);
        familyCollector.OfClass(typeof(FamilySymbol));

        foreach (FamilySymbol sym in familyCollector)
        {
            if (sym.Family.Name == fname)
            {
                familyFound = sym;
            }
        }
        UIDocument uidoc = new UIDocument(s_document);
        uidoc.PromptForFamilyInstancePlacement(familyFound);
    }
```

but it is not allowing me to place the symbol. Any help please.

Comment: Are you seeing any error messages or other useful debugging info? Please provide more information about your issue so others can help

Comment: There is no error.i build the code and run Revit 2014. Then i download revit file from external website and use loadrevitfamily() which loads the downloaded files into my Drag n Drop list. and after that i am just on Revit project. the PromptForFamilyInstancePlacement is not working for some reason.

Comment: Can you add something to your code between the foreach loop and the PromptForFamilyInstancePlacement call to ensure that familyFound is not null?  Something like if (familyFound == null) { TaskDialog.Show("Error", "familyFound is null"); }

Comment: yes i tried and getting error as "a sub-transaction can only be active inside an open Transaction". then i changed the Transactionmode to Automatic, where i get another error as "Starting a transaction from an external application running outside of API context is not allowed". Any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this has to do with how the family you are trying to place is hosted (face, workplane, vertical face, etc). In Revit 2014 & earlier PromptForFamilyInstancePlacement won't let the user change the hosting method, change views, etc.  Try placing a family that is unhosted and see if you get the same result.  You could also have a look at this workaround.

http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2015/03/postrequestforelementtypeplacement.html